# Server doesn't receive multiple write from client

Tags: c, sockets, server, client-server

The following code is simplified.I have a server with a loop:

```
while(1){
fd_c = accept(fd_skt, NULL, 0);
reading = read(fd_c, buffer, 1024);
writen(fd_c, send_ok, msg_length);
}
```

and a client with a library which contains a socket and two functions:

```
int fd_skt = -1;
int connection(){
fd_skt = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
connect(fd_skt, (struct sockaddr *) &skt_address, sizeof(skt_address))
writen("hello");
readn(); 
}

int send_another_message(){
if(fd_skt < 0)
    return error(ERR_SKT_NOT_READY);
writen("I am Bob");
readn();
}
```

If I do this in my client the server will receives two "hello":

```
connection();
connection();
```

but if i do this in my client the server will only receive "hello" and not "I am Bob":

```
connection();
send_another_message();
```

the server doesn't receive messages.

When I use send_another_message, I don't establish a new connection (because it was previously connected with previous function call).

I can post the entire code if need.

Comment: @uneven_mark edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server reads and writes only once on the connection, then the next loop iteration calls `accept` again, which will either block until there is a new connection or return an error value. In either case you overwrite your file descriptor `fd_c`. Therefore the server is no longer able to communicate with the old connection.

Accept the connection once, and keep the file descriptor around until the connection is closed, so you can reuse it for calls to `read` and `write`.

Comment: This solved the problem. Now after the client execute "send_another_message()" the client process ends. Why does the while(1) loop in the server receives two "i am bob" and after quits?

Comment: @user4789408 I can not tell you surely without a complete example code, however I suspect that you are not checking the return value of `read`. If the connection is closed, it will be `0` and your buffer contents will remain unchanged from the last read.